# Get JSONPath from JSON data (client-side or server-side)

Tags: javascript, php, json, jsonpath

I've got a JSON object like this:

```
{"photos":
   {"page":1,
    "pages":414,
    "perpage":10,
    "total":"4136",
    "photo":[
         {
            "id":"13193333",
            "owner":"picture owner",
            "title":"picture title",
            "lat":43.81919,
            "lon":11.294719,
            "url":"http:\\...."
         },
         {
            "id":"13193383",
            "owner":"picture owner",
            "title":"picture title",
            "lat":43.81919,
            "lon":11.294719,
            "url":"http:\\...."
         },

        ... (other items of "photo" like the two above).......
    ]},
    "stat":"ok"}
```

According to JSONPath specification, if I want to select all the "title" I'll use:

```
$.photos.photo[*].title
```

Now, for each distinct attribute in my JSON data I need to get its JSONPath string in a general way (for example, I don't need the exactly "title" JSONpath - like `$.photos.photo[1].title` - but the general JSONpath - like `$.photos.photo[*].title`).

**Edit:** I'll try to explain better (sorry for my poor english!), what I want to do is to obtain the JSONPath related to each attribute in this way:

```
JSON attribute: "photos"
JSONPath("photos") = $.photos

JSON attribute: "photo"
JSONPath("photo") = $.photos.photo[*]

JSON attribute: "title"
JSONPath("title") = $.photos.photo[*].title
```

and so on...

How can I solve this with JS or PHP language? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a for loop here:

```
for(var photo in $.photos) {
    console.log(photo.title);
}
```

Or push to an array

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var photo in $.photos) {
    arr.push(photo.title);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong to write my question, I've just edited it right now! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the value set into the key title you can done this in JS:

```
var titles = [];
for( i in $.photos.photo ){
    var photo = $.photos.photo[i];
    titles.push( photo.title );
    console.log( photo.title );
}
```

or this in PHP:

```
$titles = array();
$array = json_decode( $your_json_string, true );
foreach( $array['photos']['photo'] as $a ){
    $titles[] = $a['title'];
}
// now in $titles you have all titles :)
```

If you want [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) you can see the PHP docs for json_decode function.

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong to write my question, I've just edited it right now! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, no problem for your english: after realizing your goal, we seek a solution  :) then you would want to look inside your JSON structure a particular key? if you search for "titles" will return "$. titles", and so on. correct?

Comment: yeah, I found a solution: I rendered my JSON object as HTML with [JSON Visualizer](http://visualizer.json2html.com/), because I need to click on an attribute and then get its JSONPath. Then I wrote a recursive JS function to get the JSONPath when clicking on an attribute using the DOM structure (ul and li classes contain informations about the type of attribute - check the source code of the above url). Anyway, problem solved! Thank you for your support! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com), which extends the global object JSON with the method "search". With this method, you can query your JSON structure with XPath and it returns the matches as an array-like object.

Here is a snippet of example;

```
var data = {
       "photos": {
          "page": 1,
          "pages": 414,
          "perpage": 10,
          "total": "4136",
          "photo": [
             {
                "id": "13193333",
                "owner": "picture owner 1",
                "title": "picture title 1",
                "lat": 43.81919,
                "lon": 11.294719,
                "url": "http:\\...."
             },
             {
                "id": "13193383",
                "owner": "picture owner 2",
                "title": "picture title 2",
                "lat": 43.81919,
                "lon": 11.294719,
                "url": "http:\\...."
             }
          ]
       },
       "stat": "ok"
    },
    found = JSON.search(data, "//title"),
    str = '';

for (var i=0; i<found.length; i++) {
    str += found[i] +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
```

To see this in action, check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/4t4gb/

And here are more useful examples of XPath queries; http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator